# Node js requests before render page

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Recently I started learning node js and I have a question.
Before rendering a page I want to make 2 or more request to mongodb and then render page.

Currently I have sth like this:

```
exports.index = function(req, res) {

Manga.find({}, function(err, data){
    if(err) console.log('error in getting some mangas');
    res.render('index', {data: data, session: req.session.userId });
});
```

};

But I also want to get data of session user before rendering. How can I do that?

Comment: You already have `req.session.userId`. What's wrong with doing that wherever else you want it?

Comment: Suppose I have to get some other informations, make a second request :P

Comment: What other data? Is it in the session or not?

Comment: 2 requests to database

Answer (score 0):

First you need to save data, about user, in to session object and then call:

```
res.render('index', {
                     data: data,
                     sessionID: req.session.userId,
                     email:req.session.emaill,
                     user_name: req.session.user_name
                    })
```

Comment: Okey, so suppose I need to know in my navbar If user is logged in. Do I need to include those informations in every request?

Comment: Yes, by you can added it to all request to your router if you using express.

Comment: I created answer bottom.

Answer (score -1):

with express:

```
app.get("/",function(req,res,next){

  Manga.find({}, function(err, data_from_db){
    if(err) console.log('error in getting some mangas');
    //    set user data from DB in every request
    req.session.user_data=data_from_db
    next()
  })
})//get
.......
.......
app.get("/index",function(req,res){

res.render('index', {
                     data: data,
                     sessionID: req.session.userId,
                     email:req.session.emaill,
                     user_name: req.session.user_name
                    })
})//index
```

Or you can use global functions and async filters from template engine to request directly user data if page need this data. https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/api#custom-filters